# Compare list of duplicate emails using lodash underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I will try to explain what I need to do, why it is not so simple to explain.

I have 4 email lists, and in them there are duplicate items among them, need to extract these emails, for example:

```
list 1:
email1, email2, email4, email5

list 2:
email2, email3, email5, email6

list 3:
email1, email2, email7, email8

list 4:
email2, email4, email6, email7
```

I need this:
Result:

```
email1 (list1, list3)
email2 (list1, list2, list3, list4)
email3 (list2)
```

....

I'm trying to do this with javascript, because in fact these emails are in an excel ..

JSbin:
http://jsbin.com/zerexuviya/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I've just wrote using only Underscore.js: https://jsfiddle.net/alienpavlov/b0zaz5Lw/

```js
var all = {
    "list1": [
        "email1",
        "email2",
        "email3",
        "email4",
        "email5",
        "email6"
    ],
    "list2": [
        "email2",
        "email3",
        "email6",
        "email7"
    ],
    "list3": [
        "email1",
        "email3",
        "email4",
        "email5",
        "email6"
    ],
    "list4": [
        "email1",
        "email3",
        "email5",
        "email6"
    ]
};

var listOfAllEmails = _.union.apply(undefined, _.values(all));
_.each(listOfAllEmails, function(email, i) {
    var result = [];
    _.each(all, function(list, j) {
        if (_.indexOf(list, email) > -1) {
            result.push(j);
        }
    });
    if (result.length > 1) {
        //console.log(email, "=>", result);
        var div = document.getElementById("result")
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + email + " (" + result + ")<br>";
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

It was all about sorting arrays. If you have any questions feel free to ask in comments.